# Cyclic and abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

[image]

Just looking for the criteria which I would use to say if these groups are cyclic.

Like a short proof? for (i), (ii), (iii), (iv) (v)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A group is cyclic if there exists a *single* element in the group which generates the entire group. Your first group only has 27 elements, is there an element in there which generates the entire group?